# No direct script access when using include

Tags: php, include

I have a PHP powered CMS website.  I'd like to include `database.php` in a PHP script.  database.php is in the config folder and has the db connections details (pass, db_name etc).

Here is the script:

```
<?php 
  echo __DIR__ ."<br /><br />"; 
  //make sure your assumptions on directories and path are correct for the 
  //include below

  include '../application/config/database.php';

?>
```

Running the script, I get this message:

> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tslocal/textbook_scripts
>
> No direct script access.

On the first line of `database.php` is this line:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
```

I'm guessing that the CMS has somehow "protected" the config file which is preventing me from including it. What is "No direct script access"? Google gives me lots of examples of people seeking to add this functionality. I wish to remove it. Possible? Likely? How do I tell PHP to let me access database.php?

Comment: Could you add the code for `../application/config/database.php`? There's doubtless something in there checking for a variable that you're not setting in your PHP.

Comment: Could you do a Ctrl+F for the line "No direct script access" in database.php and show us the relevant code?

Comment: @andrewsi done. Not sure what syspath is

Comment: @DougFirr - it's looking for a constant called `SYSPATH` - if that's defined, it'll pass the check; otherwise, it'll `die()`. You can either search other files to see where it's defined, or just define it yourself. Alternatively, if this is just on your local machine for learning purposes, you can delete that check from the database file.

Comment: thank you @andrewsi. So it's just like a password then?

Comment: @DougFirr - pretty much. The database file is looking to see if that constant is set, but it doesn't care what the value is. It's a basic but effective way of preventing access to files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic way for going about this is somewhere in the application (prior to the loading of database.php) there is a line something along the lines of:

```
define( 'APPLICATION_LOADED', true );
```

In the database.php there is a check being performed against this, similar to:

```
if( !defined('APPLICATION_LOADED') || !APPLICATION_LOADED ) {
    die( 'No direct script access.' );
}
```

Look in database.php and whatever files it includes to determine how it is checking to see if the script is being directly accessed or not.  Then you can mimic the conditions necessary if you would like to include that file in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in database.php is the line "<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
". I'm unsure of what action I need to take here?

Comment: @Doug you should find out where in the project `SYSPATH` is being set, and ideally set it to the same value (or use the CMS' bootstrap file if it has one.). It likely has a function beyond just being a security measure for including scripts.

Comment: @Doug ideally, if you're looking to add to the project then there is probably a pre-defined set of steps that you should take in order to bootstrap the application (including some file, calling some function, etc).  Dig a bit deeper into some of the existing code to see how those files are setting the environment up.

Answer (score 5):

**I got this PHP error from Codeigniter's Email.php class called CI_Email:**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CI_Email {
   var $smtp_default_from = '';
   var $smtp_default_name = '';
   var $useragent = "CodeIgniter";
   var $mailpath  = "/usr/sbin/sendmail";

   //more code omitted

}
```

What I did was try to include this class directly like this:

```
<?php
    include("Email.php");
?>
```

And when I run it, it says:

```
No direct script access.
```

The PHP [method "defined"](https://www.php.net/defined) checks whether the given constant exists and is defined.

So for my particular class it says that BASEPATH must be defined.  So if you define it like this:

```
<?php
  define('BASEPATH', "foobar");
  include("Email.php");
?>
```

Then the error is no longer thrown.  But then we have to wonder why the developers put in this particular restriction and what will happen if we bypass it.

Comment: Excellent solution. Just what I was looking for. Thumbs up