# Php artisan error no direct script access allowed

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with **laravel 5.2** and **php 7.1.7**, the problem is that when I try to use some `artisan` command to start the server with the`php artisan serve` command I get

> no direct script access allowed

in the console and does not let me start it, I also try to make a `composer clear-cache` and then`composer update` but when I do the update I also get the

> no direct script access allowed

and I do not know how to fix some idea?

Comment: This seems to be a simulair question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384500/no-direct-script-access-when-using-include Did you try this?

Comment: isn't it `composer clearcache` ...

Comment: @Merijndk i dont have this line of code: <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.'); " on my database.php file so i dont know what to do.

Comment: @Option tried it but does not seem to work anyway

Comment: If you search for the line "No direct script access" where does it echo this and on what clause?

Comment: @Merijndk i got two matchs one on the app/AuthLDAP.php and other on config/authldap.php and both of em got the line: `if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');` starting the file

Comment: Solved it! or at least for now i just commented that line `if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');` seem to work for now :)